# Get the host names Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, hosts

I would like to do a very simple thing in an Ansible playbook.

`ansible appserver -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_hostname' | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}'`

The output of this command gives you back the hostname that you are currently running the script against. Is there any way to do this in a playbook as a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out: can be used {{ansible_hostname}} if the gather_facts are set on true.